# how to fix wrong text alignment in google Chrome for rtl

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, arabic, right-to-left

I have a problem with Chrome related to text start when using Arabic text.
Even if 'dir=rtl' is specified, the elements are not starting at the same point (In Chrome, the text lines are not perfectly aligned to right). It works fine in Firefox.

## Chrome

[image: Chrome Sample]

## Firefox

[image: Firefox Sample]

Is there a way to fix it??
Thanks

Comment: Please add some html+css code to your question, a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you have this online? please add it to jsfiddle to check all code, css and html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

- built-in CSS functionality `direction: rtl;`
- or in HTML `<body dir="rtl">`

These examples solving your issues with RTL.

BTW, [it](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)'s a good article for your case.

```css
* {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
<p>بين للإتحاد والحلفاء الألماني ٣٠. مكّن الأولى حشد تم, فرنسا أوكيناوا بال ان. كلّ عن وسوء سليمان،, كان إذ جحافل الصيني, لم جهة الأخذ للإتحاد. دول الشتوية الثالث، أم, مارد وأزيز علاقة أن قام, بحق وفرنسا اسبوعين ٣٠. فاتّبع لإعلان دنو أن, حلّت هناك استمرار
  أن الا.
</p>
```